# MYSQL to find customers that have ordered at least once a year who has submitted a feedback for that item

Tags: mysql

I want to query using MySQL to find customers that have ordered or Downloaded at least once a year for the past 3 years(2016 to 2019). However, they must have left a feedback on those items they ordered or Downloaded.

So I have these tables that I must use: Feedback, FAV(stands for Free Annual Video), and Downloads, and Contact(which has all the user info it)

```sql
SELECT c.id, c.FirstName, c.LastName
FROM contact c

JOIN download_counts dl
    on c.Id = dl.ContactId
JOIN freeannualvideo f
    on c.Id = f.ContactId
INNER JOIN (select fb.ItemId
                            from feedback fb
                            group by fb.ItemId) FBExistFAV
                            ON FBExistFAV.ItemId = f.ItemId
INNER JOIN (select fb.ItemId
                            from feedback fb
                            group by fb.ItemId) FBExistDL
                            ON FBExistDL.ItemId = dl.ItemId
WHERE  
    EXISTS (select 1 from download_counts dl where c.id = dl.ContactId and dl.DateAdded between '2016-06-30' and '2017-06-30')   
        AND EXISTS (select 1 from download_counts dl where c.id = dl.ContactId and dl.DateAdded between '2017-07-01' and '2018-06-30')   
        AND EXISTS (select 1 from download_counts dl where c.id = dl.ContactId and dl.DateAdded between '2018-07-01' and '2019-04-27') 
OR 

        (EXISTS (select 1 from freeannualvideo f where c.id = f.ContactId and f.DateAdded between '2016-06-30' and '2017-06-30')
        AND EXISTS (select 1 from freeannualvideo f where c.id = f.ContactId and f.DateAdded between '2017-07-01' and '2018-06-30') 
        AND EXISTS (select 1 from freeannualvideo f where c.id = f.ContactId and f.DateAdded between '2018-07-01' and '2019-04-27'))


GROUP BY c.Id;
```

So a contact MUST have at least ONE DL or FAV for 2017, 2018, and 2019 PLUS they needed to provide feedback for one of those DL’s or FAVs every year

Good Example: (should be pulled)
John Smith
2017 had either DL or FAV and Left feedback
2018 had either DL or FAV and Left Feedback
2019 had either DL or FAV and Left Feedback

Bad Example: (should not be pulled)
Jack Johnson
2017 had either DL or FAV and Left Feedback
2018 had either DL or FAV and Left **NO** feedback
2019 had either DL or FAV and Left Feedback